Splitting footnotes between pages to avoid a short page?
This is a scenario in which a page has a footnote, longer than the text on the page but fits the page; and the next page has a footnote in the first sentence, which is also long but fits on the page.
What is happening in my document, is that the first page includes its full footnote which is moved upward to just below a few lines of a paragraph leaving about three inches of space at the botom of the text block. The second page includes its full footnote and fills the rest of the text block with text, no unusual empty space.
My question is, Is this correct? Can that space on page 1 not be removed by moving the text with the second footnote to the first page and, perhaps, splitting both footnotes between the two pages?
(Please note that this example differs from the real document in that the example leaves the footnote at the bottom and the space in the middle on page 1. I have not been able to figure out what the difference is, yet, that moves the footnote up in my document.)
Thank you.
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,openright,twoside,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[
 includeall,
 twoside,
 inner = 1.5in,
 textwidth = 5in,
 textheight = 9in
]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[expansion=false,shrink=0]{microtype}
\usepackage[calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage[perpage,para]{footmisc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{0pt}%
  \hrule width 2in height 0.7pt \vspace*{1ex}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefnmark
  {\mbox{\textsuperscript{\color{blue}\bfseries\@thefnmark}}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]
  {\parindent 1em \indent \makebox[0pt][r]{\color{blue}\bfseries\@thefnmark.\,\,}#1}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} \fancyfoot{}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2][1-5]\footnote{\lipsum[3-6]}

Just a few words before\footnote{\lipsum[7-10]} the next footnote and \lipsum[10-12]
\end{document}




try without the para option of footmisc.

@UlrikeFischer Thank you. That removes the empty space. I've been experimenting with that for the last ten miutes or so. I'd like to have some short footnotes on the same line and others a separate block. That's the way it is in an old book I'm trying to match; but if I try two styles each has it's own number sequence.
